# Time values of minutes & seconds only in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm creating a database of music & video files. I would like one of the columns to be the "duration" or "runtime" of the file. Is there a way to show only minutes and seconds in SSMS?

I'm trying to avoid a column that looks like **00:17:30** and rather have it appear as **17:30**.

Comment: Presentation is different from storage. The data doesn't look like anything once it's stored. If you want it presented a certain way, have your presentation layer present is as such.

Comment: That is the format I'd like to use for entering the data as well. So in this case, storage and presentation are the same.

Comment: Then store it at as a varchar field and make sure you validate the data entry for the proper format.  The only downside to that is it'll make it more difficult to do any math or sorting based on the duration if you ever need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the amount of time of a music/video fragment in several ways. I'll list some, from what I think is the best way to store it to the worst:

- As an `INT`. Store the length in seconds or milliseconds whatever resolution you need. Can go up to 2^31-1 seconds/milliseconds.
- As a `TIME`. Denotes a time, restricted to 23:59:59.9999999 hours. Resolution depends on the width of the `TIME` column. Problematic if your music/video fragment is longer than 24 hours.
- As a `VARCHAR`. Not really a good storage type, preferred if all you ever want to do with the time is present it. If you want to do queries based on time of music/video you'll have to convert this to another type. Not preferred.

In terms of presentation, a `VARCHAR` would be easiest as you wouldn't need to format it any further (that's if you stored it the way you want). A `TIME` value would still need tweaking if you want to format it from a query. An `INT` would also need preparation to select the value you want to present.

I'd argue that presentation is best kept for the presentation layer. So that would be my advice. If you still insist on selecting the value as it should be presented, I'll give you the way to do it for an `INT` column with the length in seconds:

```
DECLARE @total_seconds INT = 2460;

SELECT
    CASE WHEN (@total_seconds / (60*60))=0
        THEN ''
        ELSE (CASE WHEN (@total_seconds / (60*60))<10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END) + CAST(@total_seconds / (60*60) AS VARCHAR)+':'
    END +
    CASE WHEN ((@total_seconds % (60*60)) / (60))=0
        THEN ''
        ELSE (CASE WHEN ((@total_seconds % (60*60)) / (60))<10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END) + CAST((@total_seconds % (60*60)) / (60) AS VARCHAR)+':'
    END +
    (CASE WHEN ((@total_seconds % (60*60)) % (60))<10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END) + CAST((@total_seconds % (60*60)) % (60) AS VARCHAR);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. I appreciate the time you took to provide me with this info.